# Sunflowers: Young leaves turn yellow and die

Tags: sunflowers

These sunflowers are on my window ledge getting ca 8h of sunlight per day. When they lack water the leaves start hanging dramatically. 30 minutes after watering they correct themselves. Plants look pretty healthy all around to me except for the yellow leaves. I get these on EVERY sunflower I have.

I water them thoroughly as soon as the top 3cm dried up which is around once every 4-5 days. Pots are properly drained.

[image]

Earth specs:

- Ph 7.2
- 200mg/l Nitrogen
- 170mg/l Phosphate
- 950mg/l Potassium

Comment: In none of the pictures is what you're growing them in fully visible - possibly the containers are too shallow?

Comment: Containers are same as here, ca 4.5l: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/38673/parsley-looks-sick-how-do-i-water-care-for-parsley/38677?noredirect=1

Comment: They look like shallow troughs - in which case, your sunflowers need deeper pots.

Comment: Are you sure? They are dwarf sunflowers, only get 50cm tall

Comment: Not 100% no because I don't know how many plants you have per trough, nor exactly how deep the troughs are, but I'm assuming more than one plant per trough and an average depth of 3 or 4 inches

Comment: 1-4 plants per troughs, indeed 3-4 inches. However they all get yellow leaves no matter how many plants there are.

Comment: Insufficient depth for roots, regardless of the fact they only reach 50cm (in the ground). The might make that height in deep enough pots, say 8 inches deep. Its the lower leaves you appear to be losing, not the new ones at the top by the looks of it

Comment: If you think that is the cause why not put it in an answer. I'll be doing that anyway, deeper pots..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the cause is lack of root room, since you're growing them in fairly shallow containers. Pot them up in good sized pots to allow space for good root development.